# Check an Empty column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, syntax-error

I have a `spark dataframe` that contain 4 columns:

```
(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) ==> (String, String, Int, Int)
```

In the data, sometime `col_3` is empty, for example:

```
 col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4
 col_1|col_2||col_4
```

I want to return a new `dataframe` that contain just 3 columns, after testing columns 3 and 4:

if `col_3` is empty return `col_4`
 else return `col_3`

To solve it i did this:

```
>>>
>>> def calculcolumn(col_3, col_4):
...     if (col_3 is None ):
...             return col_4
...     else:
...             return col_3
...
>>>
>>> calculcolumn( ,12)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    calculcolumn( ,12)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

But it throws `SyntaxError`, how can I resolve it?

Comment: does your code have space before your `def`? Spaces and tabs are important in Python unlike other popular languages. Please make sure what you posted is the same as your code you are trying to run.

Comment: @MooingRawr Thank you I edited my question.

Comment: What are you expecting `calculcolumn( ,12)` to do? It's a `SyntaxError` because you can't just ignore an argument. Do you mean to pass `calculcolumn(None, 12)`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell I have a spark Dataframe

Comment: @FHTMitchell I gived you an example of the structure of the dataframe, sometime the col_3 is empty between too ||

Comment: `combine_first` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `pyspark` dataframe you should be using native `pyspark` functions.  To solve your problem you can do the following to create a new column based on whether `col3` is `None`:

```
df = df.withColumn('new_col', func.when(func.col("col3").isNull(), func.col("col4")).otherwise(func.col("col3"))
```

This function will create a new column where if `col3` is null will use `col4` otherwise it will use `col3`.

Comment: To be clear, you should include in the answer;

```import pyspark.sql.functions as func```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `SyntaxError` because, well, it's a syntax error.
You must pass the first argument as well.

```
def calculcolumn(col_3, col_4):
    if (col_3 is None ):
        return col_4
    else:
        return col_3

calculcolumn(None, 12)
```

---

You can also use **[kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/1918287)** and do this:

```
def calculcolumn(col_3=None, col_4=None):
    if (col_3 is None ):
        return col_4
    else:
        return col_3

calculcolumn(col_4=12)
```